# Two SecurityConfig class in a spring boot project

Tags: java, spring-security, spring-boot

I have a SecurityConfig class already in a external library I am using.

I want to have another SecurityConfig class in order to register more filters in my project using addFilterBefore and addFilterAfter.

I just add below in my project and I get below error,

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true)
public class MySecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {       
}
```

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name
>   'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration':
>   Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: @Order on WebSecurityConfigurers must
>   be unique. Order of 100 was already used, so it cannot be used on
>   com.pearson.springtools.config.SecurityConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f0407fdb@7326eb0d
>   too.

Comment: Did you try to do what the error mentions? The `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` specifies an order of 100 (by using the `@Order(100)` anotation). So did you try to specify another order for one of your configs already by using the `@Order` annotation yourself?

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue, apply @Order(99) on your websecurity it will fix.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {
        org.activiti.spring.boot.RestApiAutoConfiguration.class,
        org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SecurityAutoConfiguration.class,
        org.activiti.spring.boot.SecurityAutoConfiguration.class})
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.onlineBankingApplication"})
@Order(99)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
```

Comment: Did not work. If i use 99 then the securityConfig class which extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter wont be invoked.

Answer (score 4):

Only WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter should be used at a time. If you want to use multiple ones in the same configuration, you have to add the @order annotation on at least one of them to specify the order in which they should be considered. To use the custom one, have it with the highest order.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true)
public class MySecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Spring boot is already using WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter under root. It doesn't allow to give same order to the second WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter. Giving different order to the second WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter (e.g. `order(1000)` ) fixed my issue.

Example code:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@Order(1000)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
   ...
}
```